# Difference between using Array.CreateInstance and new operator to instantiate an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, initialization

I can see following two ways of instantiating an int array in C#:

1. Through an API in **System.Array** abstract class:

   ```
   var arrayInstance = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 4);
   ```
2. Through various array initialization syntax:

   ```
   var arrayInstanceWithSyntax = new int[4];
   ```

Are the above two ways absolutely identical? Does the compiler converts the second syntax into first syntax at compile time itself and then embeds it into DLL as MSIL? Also, is it possible that there is some JIT magic at CLR level which happens at run time or there is no conversion taking place between the two code syntax?

Comment: Yes, they rely on the same plumbing inside the CLR, not otherwise with the compiler getting involved.  Also exposed more universally by the Type.MakeArrayType() overloads.  Second flavor is heavily micro-optimized.

Comment: I had been googling since morning to get some internals to see how compiler converts the `new int[4]` into an array type instance because `System.Array` is an abstract class in .Net and `int[]` is not something which converts directly to a type in .Net FCL. Can you please help me with some link which can help me understand more on this.

Comment: Array types are quite unusual, the CLR creates them dynamically.  You'd have to read CLR source code to get to the bottom of it.  That can keep you busy for a while, C++ skills required, but its all available from the CoreCLR github project.  Search for "AllocateArrayEx" and "FastAllocatePrimitiveArray" to find the most relevant code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They definitely create the same kind of value - unlike if you call `Array.CreateInstance` and create an array with a non-zero lower bound, for example.

However, they're not the same in terms of IL - the first is simply a method call, the second uses the `newarr` IL instruction.

There doesn't need to be any kind of "JIT magic" here - there are just two paths to create the same kind of value.

The *compile-time* type of your first variable is just `Array` though - you'd have to cast it to `int[]` for the two pieces of code to really have the same result.

I would always use the "C# native" array creation syntax where possible - only use `Array.CreateInstance` when you have an element `Type` for some reason (rather than knowing at compile time, even via a generic type parameter)... or if you're *trying* to create an array that may have a non-zero lower bound.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: No they produce different IL. You can see this yourself on [Try Roslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:%3Eil/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5nc8NIpgBuAezAATGAFkAFAEpW3TpwE0ATjFUqaCAJIQUNCOVQwAvDACCKzQgB0jFahppd+w6inIE+VEIBmUyGQZABoYABYZHFxFAF88GKA).

---

**Array.CreateInstance**

The `CreateInstance` method is a factory method in the `Array` class and it returns a type of `Array`. Here is the source code for the method:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
public unsafe static Array CreateInstance(Type elementType, int length)
{
    if ((object)elementType == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("elementType");
    if (length < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Array>() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Array>().Length == length);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Array>().Rank == 1);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    RuntimeType t = elementType.UnderlyingSystemType as RuntimeType;
    if (t == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_MustBeType"), "elementType");
    return InternalCreate((void*)t.TypeHandle.Value, 1, &length, null);
}
```

Please note the last line of code in the above method. The body of that method is just a *semi-colon* and it is a method implemented externally elsewhere. Here is the body:

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private unsafe static extern Array InternalCreate(void* elementType, int rank, int* pLengths, int* pLowerBounds);
```

Where is that implemented? It is implemented in *arraynative.cpp* class. Here is the code:

```
FCIMPL4(Object*, ArrayNative::CreateInstance, void* elementTypeHandle, INT32 rank, INT32* pLengths, INT32* pLowerBounds) {
{
    CONTRACTL {
        FCALL_CHECK;
        PRECONDITION(rank > 0);
        PRECONDITION(CheckPointer(pLengths));
        PRECONDITION(CheckPointer(pLowerBounds, NULL_OK));
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;

    OBJECTREF pRet = NULL;
    TypeHandle elementType = TypeHandle::FromPtr(elementTypeHandle);

    _ASSERTE(!elementType.IsNull());

    // pLengths and pLowerBounds are pinned buffers. No need to protect them.
    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_BEGIN_RET_0();

    CheckElementType(elementType);

    CorElementType CorType = elementType.GetSignatureCorElementType();

    CorElementType kind = ELEMENT_TYPE_ARRAY;

    // Is it ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY array?
    if (rank == 1 && (pLowerBounds == NULL || pLowerBounds[0] == 0)
# ifdef FEATURE_64BIT_ALIGNMENT
        // On platforms where 64-bit types require 64-bit alignment and don't obtain it naturally force us
        // through the slow path where this will be handled.
        && (CorType != ELEMENT_TYPE_I8)
        && (CorType != ELEMENT_TYPE_U8)
        && (CorType != ELEMENT_TYPE_R8)
#endif
    )
    {
        // Shortcut for common cases
        if (CorTypeInfo::IsPrimitiveType(CorType))
        {
            pRet = AllocatePrimitiveArray(CorType, pLengths[0]);
            goto Done;
        }
        else
        if (CorTypeInfo::IsObjRef(CorType))
        {
            pRet = AllocateObjectArray(pLengths[0], elementType);
            goto Done;
        }

        kind = ELEMENT_TYPE_SZARRAY;
        pLowerBounds = NULL;
    }

    {
        // Find the Array class...
        TypeHandle typeHnd = ClassLoader::LoadArrayTypeThrowing(elementType, kind, rank);

        DWORD boundsSize = 0;
        INT32* bounds;
        if (pLowerBounds != NULL)
        {
            if (!ClrSafeInt < DWORD >::multiply(rank, 2, boundsSize))
                COMPlusThrowOM();
            DWORD dwAllocaSize = 0;
            if (!ClrSafeInt < DWORD >::multiply(boundsSize, sizeof(INT32), dwAllocaSize))
                COMPlusThrowOM();

            bounds = (INT32*)_alloca(dwAllocaSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
            {
                bounds[2 * i] = pLowerBounds[i];
                bounds[2 * i + 1] = pLengths[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            boundsSize = rank;

            DWORD dwAllocaSize = 0;
            if (!ClrSafeInt < DWORD >::multiply(boundsSize, sizeof(INT32), dwAllocaSize))
                COMPlusThrowOM();

            bounds = (INT32*)_alloca(dwAllocaSize);

            // We need to create a private copy of pLengths to avoid holes caused
            // by caller mutating the array
            for (int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
                bounds[i] = pLengths[i];
        }

        pRet = AllocateArrayEx(typeHnd, bounds, boundsSize);
    }

    Done:;
    HELPER_METHOD_FRAME_END();

    return OBJECTREFToObject(pRet);
}
```

As you can see `Array.CreateInstance` uses an external DLL implemented elsewhere, outside of managed code.

---

**new int[4];**

This is native to C# so the C# compiler will take care of it and create the array. How? I am not sure.

I hope that clarifies things a little.