# How to find extern source code for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580956/difference-between-array-createinstance-and-using-the-new-operator-to-create-new) question and thought I would look inside of the `Array` source code to see how it is implemented. Therefore, I looked [in .NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,9afc2f2b6acee49e) for the `CreateInstance` method and found that it calls an external method whose body is a *semi-colon* and implemented elsewhere. Here is what it looks like:

```
private unsafe static extern Array 
    InternalCreate(void* elementType,int rank,int *pLengths,int *pLowerBounds);
```

**Question:**

How do I find where the implementation for the above external method is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find the source code for any `extern` methods, do the following:

1. Find the name of the `extern` method. In my case it is `InternalCreate`.
2. Go [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/419629fdc3e51c6c28467bf1b57b7fcd80dc8360/src/vm/ecalllist.h) and find the mapping of the method to the external method. In my case I needed to find `InternalCreate` and here is what the mapping looks like. The name of the class is `ArrayNative` and the method is `CreateInstance`:

   ```
   FCFuncElement("InternalCreate", ArrayNative::CreateInstance)
   ```
3. Find the mapped class [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/tree/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/classlibnative/bcltype). In my case I needed `arraynative` and I needed the method `CreateInstance`. The implementation is right there and I am copying it here but removing the body for brevity:

   ```
   FCIMPL4(Object*, ArrayNative::CreateInstance, 
       void* elementTypeHandle, INT32 rank, INT32* pLengths, INT32* pLowerBounds)
   {
       //...
   }
   ```

There you will find the implementation and study the code.

Comment: One small note, those links are for the .NET Core runtime. The runtime used by the full .NET framework can be different than the code shown in the `dotnet/coreclr` repo, for example it is possible there could be a native type in the CLR that is used in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ that is not in the Core CLR (Not that I know of any that are). One possible work around, use https://source.dot.net/ instead to do the intial browsing so you see the external dependencies of .NET Core instead of the full .NET framework.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for that note-I did not even realize it was the .NET Core Runtime I was looking at. Can you please elaborate on your workaround? If I wanted to put your workaround in my answer, what step will it go into?

Comment: It is okay, they maintained the same codebase for both the full and the core versions of the CLR.  Just a bunch of #ifdefs to turn off features.  That might not be true forever, coreclr is likely to diverge over time, but true enough for now.

Comment: The workaround would go in to the step in the question instead of the answer. You would change *"Therefore, I looked in [.NET source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,9afc2f2b6acee49e) for the `CreateInstance` method"* to *"Therefore, I looked in [.NET source code](https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs.html#9afc2f2b6acee49e) for the `CreateInstance` method"* (click the two links and check your URL bar)