# Since the C# Array class is abstract, how is it instantiated?

Tags: c#

I just started to learn C# and I came across the fact that Array is an abstract class, not a concrete one.  I am wondering how it is possible that array instances can be created if it is declared as abstract in the documentation (as seen in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0).

Comment: you can not directly instantiate the `Array` class, if you looking for a way to instantiate an array read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

Comment: As per remarks on the linked article, the compiler is allowed to derive from it, and only the system and the compiler. It's a special class.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914523/mystery-behind-system-array#comment29631862_19914523 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163297/how-do-arrays-in-c-sharp-partially-implement-ilistt/11164210#11164210 and note that they are speaking of single-dimensional-zero-based arrays (the normal arrays). In .NET there are multidimensional arrays `int[1, 2]` and non-zero based arrays (array for example that have the first index at 1). Those are based on a different sleight of hand. "Standard" arrays are supported by `SZArrayHelper` (Single dimension, Zero based)

Comment: _"how it is possible that array instances can be created"_ -- how is it possible that `TextWriter` and `TextReader` instances can be created? How is it possible that `Stream` instances can be created? How is possible that _any_ `abstract` class can be created? Frankly, this question doesn't make sense...you are either asking how something can be done that is obvious (i.e. you create **subclasses** of `Array`, not `Array` itself), or you are asking how something that _can't_ be done can be done (i.e. create bare instances of `Array`). Either way, not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Array' is an abstract class, so it cannot be instantiated directly.  However it has an static 'CreateInstance' method, which creates an instance of a concrete implementation of an array containing elements of the required type.
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32_

and also: [Difference between Array.CreateInstance and using the new operator to create new array instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580956/difference-between-array-createinstance-and-using-the-new-operator-to-create-new)